# Unity3d - Projeny and Google Play Services

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been developing a game for a while now in Unity3d and I've been using a project and package manager called Projeny to split my code into logical projects and keep plugins/packages separate.

Now it's time to add in Leaderboards and I'd like to use Google Play Games but it seems that the Google Play Games generates files when it initially loads and when you create a build. ( these files are in the Plugins/Android folder )

Does anyone know how to get Projeny to work with Google Play Games? I'm thinking if I can get either Projeny to not care that Google Play Games is creating files or to specify where Google Play Games can make files, then it'll work.

Ref: Projeny Plugin - https://github.com/modesttree/Projeny
Ref: Google Play Games Plugin - https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 0):

For projeny to work right, everything has to be placed in package folders.  This can be an issue when using Projeny because some asset store packages are no compatible out of the box and so you sometimes have to tweak locations of items.

In this case, it sounds like Google Play Games requires that you place something inside a special Unity folder for including Android specific files.  What I would recommend is copying these generated files into a new package, and then creating a `ProjenyPackage.yaml` file inside this new package (named, for example, GooglePlayGames-Android) with the following contents:

`FolderType: AndroidProject`

Now, create a file named `ProjenyPackage.yaml` in the Google Play Games package folder with the following contents:

`Dependencies:
- GooglePlayGames-Android`

Then if you update the directories in your unity project then hopefully Projeny will place the files correctly.  Should be placed in Plugins/Android/GooglePlayGames-Android/ after that.  I'm not sure what the purpose of these files are, but there may be additional issues if the GooglePlayGames package requires that these files be in the root folder Plugins/Android/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid that doesn't help, I was already doing that, the issue is that each time a build is done, it generates new files, in the same place "Plugins/Android", but it regenerates it and Projeny fails because of it.